# AWS s3 and minio incompatibility signature checking if url params contains ;

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I have a problem with incompatibility between `minio(RELEASE.2019-07-17T22-54-12Z)` and `AWS S3`

1. I request the generation of pre-signed URL for download file from `minio`
2. From `minio` I got pre-signed URL that contains part `response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22test.zip%22`
3. Then `Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.25.0` make the request to get this file
4. `minio` return below error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
    </Message>
    ...
</Error>
```

5. I have found out that signature is wrong because `Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.25.0` before send request encode `%3B` to `;` that change signature

My question is why `AWS S3` can handle this case without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in `minio`. I have reported it here: https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/8897
I can confirm that the last version of `minio(RELEASE.2020-01-16T22-40-29Z)` is also affected.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why AWS S3 can handle this case without problems?

AWS S3 is forgiving when it comes to these kind of issues, hence it accepts the requests even though there is a problem with the request.

Check if using the same presigned-url works with `curl` command with MinIO (Since curl would not modify the url.

Comment: Of course I have checked that signature is correct when I use another client(include curl)